# MVC5 Authentication redirects to Login Page even after login

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I am working on MVC5 Project, it works fine on my system but it's behaving strange after deployment on server. I used OWIN for authentication, it works fine for first login, but after few seconds if I refresh the page, it redirects me back to the login page (This on happens on deployed server).

My Code:

```
     public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
     {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);}
```

I used [Authorize] on my controller.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here's my login code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginUserModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.userName, model.password);
            if (user != null)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add your view aswell please?

Comment: Check This page out :- http://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/understanding-the-owin-external-authentication-pipeline/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added machineKey and sessionState in my Web.config file and that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, its either that the cookie is not being set correctly or at all. Or that the ModelState for some reason is not valid and your redirect is never hit.

Check out the link :-

http://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/understanding-the-owin-external-authentication-pipeline/

It should help with your configuration of OWIN middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the help Derek, the problem was with session state and I resolved it by making few changes to my Web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which was caused by not using SSL. Choose the project in Solution Explorer, hit F4 and change to use SSL. Login requires SSL, a setting you can change but if set wrong it causes this confusing loop.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It still keeps redirecting to login page if I refresh the landing page. Any other idea?